# How to use RouteValues using MvcPaging2.0 in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, paging

Html helper `@Html.Pager` from **MvcPaging 2.0.** has `.Options(o => o.RouteValues(object RouteValues))` which can return Model back to Controller,but MvcPaging requires this helper to be filled with `IPagedList<model>` in View that he lives in. This is the Model that generates table and paging. What is the best way to implement mvcpaging 2.0. using SearchModel for search and Model to display results?

*Example:*

**MODELS:**

```
public class SearchModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dob { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

**VIEW:** 
Index.cshtml

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "SearchPerson", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "GET",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "main_search_result_table_id"
}))
{    
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LastName)
    <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
}
 <div id="main_search_result_table_id">
      @{Html.RenderPartial("_InitPartialEmpty");}
 </div>
```

_ResultPartial.cshtml

```
@using MvcPaging
@model IPagedList<Models.Person>

<table>
@foreach (var p in Model)
{
<tr>
    <td>@p.FirstName</td>
    <td>@p.LastName</td>
    <td>@p.Dob</td>
    <td>@p.City</td>
</tr>
}
<table>

 @Html.Pager(Model.PageSize, Model.PageNumber,
                 Model.TotalItemCount,  new AjaxOptions 
 { 
     UpdateTargetId = "main_search_result_table_id"
 }).Options(o => o.RouteValues(Model)) //==> IPagedList<Models.Person>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
public ActionResult SearchPerson(int? page,SearchModel person)
{
    List<Person> result= adapter.GetPersons(person);

    int currentPageIndex = page.HasValue ? page.Value - 1 : 0;

    return PartialView("_ResultPartial", 
                result.ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, 10, result.Count()));
}
```

The question is how to implement MvcPaging2.0 using model for search?Or is there another way, a better way, to have complex searches and not using model to transfer data query? Any thoughts?

I am using [MvcPaging 2.0.](http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2012/04/23/mvcpaging-2-0/) ,[docs](https://github.com/martijnboland/MvcPaging)

**EDIT:***

Thanks Darin for answer but I manage to pull it of like this:

*_ResultPartial.cshtml*

```
@Html.Pager(Model.PageSize, Model.PageNumber,
             Model.TotalItemCount,  new AjaxOptions 
{ 
 UpdateTargetId = "main_search_result_table_id"
 }).Options(o => o.Action("AjaxPaging"))
```

*CONTROLLER*

```
public ActionResult SearchPerson(int? page,SearchModel person)
{
    IQueryable<Person> query= adapter.GetPersons(person);

    Session["SearchQuery"] = query;

    int currentPageIndex = page.HasValue ? page.Value - 1 : 0;

    List<Person> persons = query.ToList();

    return PartialView("_ResultPartial", 
                persons.ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, 10, persons.Count()));
}


public ActionResult AjaxPaging(int? page)
{
    IQueryable<Person> query = Session["SearchQuery"] as IQueryable<Person>;

    int currentPageIndex = page.HasValue ? page.Value - 1 : 0;

    List<Person> persons = query.ToList();

    return PartialView("_ResultPartial", 
                persons.ToPagedList(currentPageIndex, 10, persons.Count()));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a custom extension method that will harvest all query string parameters and add them to the page link in addition to all the currentPage, pageNumber, totalItemCount, etc ... stuff:

```
public static class PagerOptionsBuilderExtensions
{
    public static PagerOptionsBuilder AddFromQueryString(
        this PagerOptionsBuilder builder, 
        HttpRequestBase request
    )
    {
        foreach (string item in request.QueryString)
        {
            builder.AddRouteValue(item, request.QueryString[item]);
        }
        return builder;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
.Options(o => o.RouteValues(Model).AddFromQueryString(Request))
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But be careful with this because by defaut MvcPaging use "page" item so to avoid a duplicate key in the builder i suggest to add a simple condition if(item.ToUpper() != "PAGE") { builder.AddRouteValue(item, request.QueryString[item]); }